# MPAndroid chart need to add values using array list

Tags: android, arrays, mpandroidchart

I have an `arraylist` of `object`, I need to create a `line chart` using this array of object, I have the minimum y value and maximum y value for y axis, and also I have string array for x axis. This 2 arrays doesn't have the same length.

My problem is in `MPAndroidChart` library I can create a line chart using just static values. But here I need to create it using dynamic values.

```
  for (int i=0;i<deals.size();i++) {

        float y = (float)deals.get(i).getPrice();

        values.add(new Entry(y, y));
    }

    // create a dataset and give it a type
    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1");
    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setValueTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
    set1.setDrawCircles(false);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    set1.setFillAlpha(65);
    set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(set1);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    data.setValueTextSize(9f);

    // set data
    mChart.setData(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create ArrayList values , which i think you created upon adding values.add(new Entry(y, y)); you have to give index in second argument you are giving value in both so you should do something like values.add(new Entry(y,i));

Hope it helps, Do let me know if it works. I used Mpcharts library alot in case of further queries you can contact me. Best of luck !

Comment: If its ok for you then share your project i will fix it for you as i have nothing to do today :)

Comment: great do u have skype ??

Comment: yes I do imsaadlakhan@outlook.com but you can share it on dropbox and give me the link or google drive its feasible for me

Comment: its works now, i need to tap on the screeen to see the chart :O , now how can i add spaces between x values and make the chart scroll horizontally

Comment: Oh thats good!
you can zoom it by pinching outside by default it can zoom.Check it if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138223/discussion-between-amalo-and-m-saad-lakhan).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two data set 
1. For Y axis data 
2. For X axis label

you can simply skip X value if the corresponding index has not value to display.

```
ArrayList<YourData> data= new ArrayList<>();
data.addAll(getDataFromDataSource());

ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= data.size() - 1; i++) {            
        if(data.getName().equals(null)){
           xVals.add(i,"");
        }
        xVals.add(i, data.getName());
        yVals.add(new Entry(data.getValue(), i));
}
```

After creating data source, create `LineDataSet` object to apply Y axis line color, line width, etc.

```
LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setValueTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
set1.setDrawCircles(false);
set1.setDrawValues(false);
set1.setFillAlpha(65);
set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
```

Create `LineData` object for X axis labels

```
LineData data = new LineData(xVals, set1);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
data.setValueTextSize(9f);
```

And finally pass `LineData` object to `LineChart`

```
mChart.setData(data);
```

Your final code should look like this

```
ArrayList<YourData> data= new ArrayList<>();
data.addAll(getDataFromDataSource());

ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= data.size() - 1; i++) {            
        if(data.getName().equals(null)){
           xVals.add(i,"");
        }
        xVals.add(i, data.getName());
        yVals.add(new Entry(data.getValue(), i));
}

LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setValueTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
set1.setDrawCircles(false);
set1.setDrawValues(false);
set1.setFillAlpha(65);
set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);

LineData data = new LineData(xVals, set1);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
data.setValueTextSize(9f);

mChart.setData(data);
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: LineData must takes ILineDataSet not xvalues and LineDataSet, which version of mp android chart you use

Comment: its 2.x.x, what's your version?

Comment: im using version 3.0 i think this is the problem so what x,x u use ?